# How to create dynamic char array with dynamic row's and column's size

Tags: c, arrays, vector, dynamic, malloc

I've attempted to create a dynamic char array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void push(int *rows, char **arr, char *value) {
    int colum = strlen(value);
    arr = malloc(*rows * sizeof(char *));
    arr[*rows] = malloc(colum * sizeof(char));
    arr[*rows] = value;
    printf("%s\n", arr[*rows]);

    // increment rows variable
    (*rows)++;
}

int main() {
    int rows = 0;
    char **arr = NULL;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(char *));
    push(&rows, arr, "test");

    printf("%s", arr[0]);
}
```

This outputs:

```
test
(null)
```

Indicating that the value `test` is not being stored into the `**arr` pointer array correctly.

I want to print the contents of `**arr`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly you want in ur output can u plz elaborate

Comment: `arr` is a local variable in the function. Setting it does not change the caller's variable. Need to either pass in a triple pointer (yuck) or pass it back in the return value.

Comment: @Aditya Shende  edited.

Comment: @kaylum  could you provide an example of the latter solution and I will accept it as an answer.